# How do I assign default pages of Ultimate User plugin in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am a beginner in WordPress and tried to use the Ultimate User plugin. Installation seemed fine and when I add the default pages to my menu options, and click, it will have a "/?page_id=12" path (or different numbers) but the same page as I see as a home page. I was expecting to see pages such as "members" with a list of members or "profile" with your profile details.

I have tried creating a blank page.php file in my drive but that made the entire page blank, instead of the same contents as the home page.
I have just the `add_theme_support('menus');` line in my functions.php file.
There are some .php files in "templates" folder of the plugin but I am not sure if I should copy that file to my "themes" folder, or do anything with it to show the right page.

It would be appreciated if someone could give me some tips to solve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: wordpress plugins usually have their own support for each plugin. try to check out wordpress.org

Comment: Thank you very much Hendra. I have asked in wordpress.org and I will wait for their response there.